# How can i make this from string to HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, innerhtml

so i came across this problem where my code gets spitted to string instead of html that im trying to achieve.My question is how can i transform this into innerHTML before spitting? Is it even possible to do this if i push it to the array? My goal is to make this like "to do list app" that has multiple inputs that spit each value to each row.

```
class Forma extends React.Component {

constructor(){
  super()
  this.state ={
    name: '',
    birth: '',
    age: '',
    items: []
  }
  this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
  this.submitItem = this.submitItem.bind(this)
}

handleInputChange(event){
let name = event.target.name
let birth = event.target.birth
let age = event.target.age
let value = event.target.value

this.setState({ [name] : value, [birth] : value, [age] : value})
}

submitItem (){
  let items = this.state.items
  let item = this.state.name
  let birth =this.state.birth
  let age = this.state.age
  let i = "<th>"
  let z = "</th>"

  let all =i + item + z + i + birth + z + i + age +z
  items.push(all)
 
  
  this.setState({ items: items})
}


  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>To do List</h1>
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></input>
        <input type="text" name="birth" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></input>
        <input type="text" name="age" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></input>
          <button onClick={this.submitItem}>Submit</button>
          

          {this.state.items.map((all) => {
            
            return(
              <tr>{all}<button type="submit" className="delete">Delete</button></tr>

           
            );
          })}
          
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: As an aside, as advice, you should always write actual variable names. Those little one letter variables make it very hard for anybody to process what is happening and it can help you identify bugs quicker if you make them expressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) can be used to render html from string

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

```
<tr dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{all}}><button type="submit" className="delete">Delete</button></tr>
```

Comment: <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> Thats the error im getting when doing so.

Comment: do you have javascript disabled? and what browser are you using, also which version

Comment: Just tested it , its enable.

Comment: Error that terminal gave me:  Only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`  react/no-danger-with-children

Comment: try to move the ``<button type="submit" className="delete">Delete</button>`` to the ``all`` variable cause you can't have multiple ``dangerouslySetInnerHTML``

Comment: also make sure there aren't any spaces between the ``button`` and ``tr`` elements that might cause this error as well

Comment: Thank you very much mate, you led me on the right road and i figured this out with your help!! I added this line on map : (`<tr dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:all + y}}></tr>`)